# Converting Pascal to PSI

Tags: forces, pressure, unit-conversion

Trying to do a basic unit version and getting stuck. Also, I tried formatting this with MathJax or whatever it's called but it looked terrible.  Couldn't get it to look right so if anyone can assist with that that would be appreciated.

A Pascal is defined as $\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{m} \, \mathrm{s}^2}$. When doing the conversion, I get close to the final answer, but not quite there.

1 Pa = $\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{m} \, \mathrm{s}^2} \cdot \left(\frac{1 \, \mathrm{lb}}{0.4536 \,\mathrm{kg}}\right) \cdot \left[\frac{1 \,\mathrm{m}}{39.37 \,\mathrm{in}}\right]^2$

I then end up with: $0.0014 \, \frac{\mathrm{lb} \, \mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2 \, \mathrm{in}^2}$

I know this is close to the final answer, as the actual conversion from Pascal to PSI is 0.00014, so I am off by a factor of 10.  What am I missing??

Comment: Ryan, I taught high school physics for 13 years, and I noted that many students insisted on using their own methods to solve problems even though they were getting incorrect answers, and even though I was showing them a better way to work their problems.  Are you willing to explicitly follow a method that will greatly decrease your chance of making an error, even if this method is longer than what you are using?

Comment: Sure, although in this particular case all I am looking for is to figure out what factor of 10 I am missing.

Comment: My method will greatly decrease the chance of your type of error for this and all unit conversions.  I'll work something up and post it.

Comment: The “pounds” in PSI is pounds of force, not pounds of mass. Otherwise it would not be a unit of pressure.

Comment: In my first step above, 1 lb/0.4536 kg is pound-mass.  Correct?

Comment: Yet another reason to stick to metric; who in their right mind defines the unit for mass and force to have the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dimensions of Pascal**

Pascal is the SI unit for pressure, which is force per unit area.  In SI units, this corresponds to $N/m^2$.  To get to SI base units, note that Newton's 2nd law can be used.  Thus, the following are the base SI units for a Pascal:

$Pa = \frac{N}{m^2} = \frac{ma}{L^2} = \frac{kg-m/s^2}{m^2} = \frac{kg}{m-s^2}$

**Dimensions of psi**

psi is also a pressure term, so it represents a force per unit area.  The units of psi are $\frac{ib_f}{in^2}$.  Note the subscript "f" on "lb".  This represents pounds force, which is distinctly different than pounds mass.  Again, use Newton's 2nd law to arrive at the units of pounds force:

$lb_f = lb_m * 32.2 \frac{ft}{s^2}$

**Recommendations for unit conversions**

There are several practices that greatly reduce the chance of errors when doing unit conversions.  Those practices are:

- Draw square brackets and draw a horizontal division bar between those brackets.  It is important to draw a HORIZONTAL division bar rather than a slash, because the horizontal bar makes it much easier to determine whether or not units cancel later on in the procedure
- Write the units that you want to convert inside the brackets just drawn
- Assuming that there are units in the numerator and denominator, choose one to convert
- Draw the next pair of square brackets, with a horizontal division bar
- Write UNITS first in the numerator and the denominator, ensuring that units cancel properly between the numerators and denominators of your brackets
- Now, write the numbers that match the units in the bracket you just drew.  For example, if your 2nd bracket has units of $\frac{m}{ft}$, you would write 1 in the numerator and 3.28 in the denominator.  You will know that the numbers are correct when you check the ratio in the brackets.  That ratio should equate to 1, and the ratio of 1 m divided by 3.28 ft does indeed equal 1 because 1 m equals 3.28 ft
- Continue with brackets until all units in the numerator and the denominator are converted to the units that you want
- Make sure that you lightly cross out all of the units that cancel, and inspect the result to ensure dimensional consistency.  For example, if you have ft in the numerator of one factor and one other occurrence of ft in the denominator of any factor, $\frac{ft}{ft}$ equates to 1, and it cancels out of the problem

**Converting Pa to psi**

Using the recommendations above, note that the units of Pa are:
$[\frac{kg}{m-s^2}]$, and that is the first factor to write.  Starting with the numerator, it is seen that the units are kg, which is a mass, and this needs to be converted to $lb_f$ in order to arrive at psi.  Thus, the complete set of factors required to convert 1 Pa to psi is as follows:

$[\frac{1 kg}{m-s^2}][\frac{2.2 lb_m}{1 kg}][\frac{1 lb_f-s^2}{32.2 ft-lb_m}][\frac{3.28 ft}{1 m}][\frac{1 m}{39.37 in}]^2 = 0.00014458 psi$

Comment: Is the notation of using a minus sign (`-`) for division a common thing for physicists? This is the first time I have ever seen this, after years of studying and working in engineering...

Comment: I've never seen this notation before and it is extremely confusing. I'd think it would be much more natural to use a \cdot or something like that.

Comment: I'm using the "-" to indicate that the units are multiplied by each other.  For example, "$m-s^2$" is meters multiplied by seconds multiplied again by seconds.  I could have just as easily used "*".  Note that using nothing at all would have also possibly been confusing because cramming several units together would have looked like a new type of unit.

Comment: The commenters suggest using `\cdot`: e.g. `\mathrm{m}\cdot\mathrm{s}^2` will yield $\mathrm{m}\cdot\mathrm{s}^2$ (notice the `\mathrm` to get the correct upright formatting of the unit symbols).

Answer (score 4):

Converting kilograms to pounds, even though useful in a grocery store, is not a valid operation from point of view of dimensions. One is mass, the other is force. Newtons to pounds will be ok and give you the right answer.

Comment: Not sure I follow

Comment: nasu, there is a pound mass and a pound force, and they are not the same thing.

Comment: Did I say otherwise?

Comment: @Ryan_C a mass became a force only if you multiply by a relevant acceleration (g, in case of weight), which incidentally is very close to the factor 10 you are missing ...

Comment: @nasu You say _"Converting kilograms to pounds, even though useful in a grocery store, is not a valid operation from point of view of dimensions."_ But in grocery store you convert kilograms to pound mass, and it's a perfectly valid operation. If someone knows pound mass is a thing but doesn't understand that you're talking solely about pound force here, this answer is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Convert Pa in $\rm{kg\over {m\sec^2}}$ to $\rm{lbm \over {ft\sec^2}}$ then use $\rm{1\ lbf = 32.174\ {{lbm\ ft} \over sec^2}}$ to obtain pressure in $\rm{lbf \over ft^2}$, then convert to $\rm{lbf \over in^2}$.

Note: in English units $\rm{1\ lbf = 32.174 \ {{lbm\ ft} \over sec^2}}$.

Comment: The typography hurts the eyes.

Comment: Yes, I edited to hopefully improve the formatting.

Comment: It is weird: sometimes there is space after lb, sometimes not; sometimes the c of sec² is below the baseline, sometimes not. Anyway, I prefer symbols for units not to be italicized.

Comment: @Pieter it's not only your preference, it's the requirement of BIPM for the SI units (see SI Brochure section 5.2: _"Unit symbols are printed in upright type regardless of the type used in the surrounding text"_). For consistency, it's natural to use the same rule for non-SI units.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you treat pascals as "Newtons per square meter". PSI is "Pounds per square inch", right? Well, both inches and meters are units of length, and both newtons and pounds are units of force. So, try to convert the newtons to pounds and meters to inches using a simple conversion factor. Dont lay out all the units kg m * s^2. It's easier to do it the other way. **Hope this helped!** :) Im new here by the way, just signed up 5 min ago. :D

Comment: The difference between lbf and lbm (English units) is part of the confusion

Comment: Right. For some reason, the U.S. still uses the Imperial system/English units, which gives confusion. All standard units can be converted to each other though, just so long as they represent the same physical quantities. NO matter how hard you try, you can turn 500 inches to hours!  Same thing goes for turning kg into pounds, they represent different physical quantities. Kg represents mass, the English unit for mass is the slug. Only standard units of force, like Newtons, can be turned into pounds. Glad I could help though! :D

Comment: You can convert kg to lbm: 1 kg = 2.2 lbm.  See my answer and the answer by David White.

Answer (score 0):

The Pascal is, as others have answered, defined as $1$ $N$ acting on a surface of $1$ $m^2$.

$$N = ma$$
$$a = g$$
$$g \approx 10 \frac{m}{s^2} (1)$$
(1) earth's gravitational constant

And there is your missing zero. 1 Pascal is $0.1\frac{kg}{ms^2}$ if you wish to translate to "kilograms of force on the surface of the earth".

Comment: Your first 3 equations confuse quantities and units of those quantities.